# How can I do a classifer in LDA (manual)

Tags: r, classification, lda

I'm trying to make the classification rule of LDA in R , this is using the Euclidean's distance, `g(x)= t(w)x - wo`, `w` is my eigenvector, `x` my test data, `wo` the mean of the two classes.

My question is, how can I pass the model (project data) to model prediction (`True`-`False`)?  thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the MASS package? Specifically `lda` and `predict.lda`.

Comment: yes, I know this package, but I need do it by hand

Comment: The package source would be instructive in that case.